# What is the meaning of "occupied a sort of island" in this text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Perisapor (an ancient city) occupied a sort of island, while at the same time it was completely surrounded with a double wall.”

Comment: I've downvoted, too many ELL users cite passages and sentences from unnamed texts. Please cite your source. I'm happy to retract the downvote when this is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

George Rawlinson again.

> Situated between the Euphrates and one of the numerous canals derived from it, and further protected by a trench drawn across from the canal to the river, Perisabor occupied a sort of island, while at the same time it was completely surrounded by a double wall.

[George Rawlinson "Perisabor"](https://books.google.com/books?id=DIljDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1673&lpg=PT1673&dq=%22occupied%20a%20sort%20of%20island%22&source=bl&ots=sgQIhkmuQX&sig=ACfU3U1NlkknzMXU_CKC19zX_wirgAE1XA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC_-zhqZjqAhXMXM0KHf0LCx0Q6AEwAXoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22occupied%20a%20sort%20of%20island%22&f=false)

An island is land surrounded by water. Perisabor (note spelling) was mostly surrounded by water (the Euphrates river, and the canal and trenches), so it was on (occupied) a space that was almost (sort of) an island. This situation, along with its double wall, made it more defensible.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of island = like an island or island-like.  On the face of it (it = your bare-bones extract), I assume the city was located on a hill (which could pass for an island in a sea of level landscape).  Otherwise, it might be located on a tidal island like Mont-Saint-Michel, which only appears as an island during a few high tides each year.  The writer seems to be making that comparison.